# Location for apple-app-site-association file

Tags: ios

I have a web app and an iOS app that I have enabled universal links for, as per [this guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/AppSearch/UniversalLinks.html).

The guide states that the file `apple-app-site-association` must be in the root of the domain, which I have done.

Why then, is my web app's error logs full of 404's for the URL `/.well-known/apple-app-site-association` ?

Comment: What did you put in associated domains? Is everything accesible via HTTPS without redirects? Or do you mean that everything is working and you just have some weird logs server-side?

Comment: Yes, I'm pretty sure everything is working with the universal links, but I've got loads of these logs server side

Comment: Are they happening when you are testing/using the app or just at random times?

Comment: Theres a lot of them, it looks like every time the app is used they're firing off

Answer (score 0):

> devices running iOS 9.3 will first request /.well-known/apple-app-site-association for the apple-app-site-association file that is required to implement Universal Links and Shared Web Credentials. If the file is not found in this location, then the device will request the file in the root of the web server, as with prior releases of iOS 9.

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/qa/qa1919/_index.html